# what is the right way to display the points on the graph on top of the axes?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Sometimes there is a need to display points on the graph on top of the axes so that the result looks something like this:

[image]

Previously, when I used R, it took a certain amount of alchemy to get the desired result: first the size of the rendering field was set, then the position of the axis, and at the end data points were drawn on top of all this:

```
f <- rnorm(10, mean=5, sd=1)
plot(x = f, y = c(rep(0, 10)), xlim = c(-1, 11), ylim = c(0, 1),
axes = FALSE, box = FALSE, xaxs = "i", ylab="")
abline(h=0)
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 10, 2), pos = 0, tck = -0.02)
points(x = f, y = c(rep(0, 10)), cex=1.0, pch = 21,
col="black", bg="white", lwd = 1)
```

Now I'm trying to translate my entire workflow to Julia and I want to find some alternative for such visualization. I usually use Plots.jl with GR backend. The trick I used in R does not work in this case: when adding a layer above, it is still cut off by the canvas borders set at the beginning:

```
c = vcat(1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 12.0, 21.0)
plot(c, zeros(length(c)), seriestype = :scatter,
markersize=5, markershape=:circle, color = :white, label = "", ylims=(0,Inf))
plot!(c, zeros(length(c)), seriestype = :scatter,
markersize=5, markershape=:circle, color = :white, label = "")
```

Result:

[image]

What is the most rational way to get such graphics with Julia?

Comment: This is not ideal but almost what you want `scatter([-1, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], yaxis=nothing, framestyle=:origin, legend=false, grid=false, ylim=(-0.01, 0.01), aspect_ratio=2.3)`

Comment: This is very similar to the desired result, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to plot on the x-axis by using `framestyle=:origin` or `framestyle=:zerolines`

```
scatter(c, zeros(length(c)), 
        markersize=5, markershape=:circle, 
        color = :red, label="", framestyle=:zerolines)
```

[image]

and if you want to show just the x-axis

```
scatter(c, zeros(length(c)), markersize=5, 
        markershape=:circle, color = :red, legend=false, 
        framestyle=:origin, yaxis=false, grid=false, aspect_ratio=1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is not suitable. The goal is not to display the points at the zero level, but to display the points on top of the axes. They do not have a real value on the Y axis, so their display inside the graph field will lead to an erroneous perception of the graph

Comment: @AntonDegterev I have updated my answer. Hope that solves your problem!